# Ways to get data from Sharepoint out of sharepoint environment

Tags: 2007, list, development, web-services, security-token-service

My question is
**Can someone tell me the possible ways, I can get data from a sharepoint 2007 list, which is secured with SSL/Https for a Windows 7 gadget(uses HTML/Java Script)**,

(I asked my senior developers and they told me that a client first fills in a form, which is validated by ISA server and gives client a cookie, which he uses later on access the sharepoint sites he got access to, which makes me assume that its a forms authentication but then am not sure if its windows authentication as users fill in a form @ IE but if I open up same portal in chrome, a windows pops up and ask for username and password)

I have been looking at different ways, but am not sure which one exactly gonna work on in this scenario.

**EDIT:**
After research on Windows/Forms Authentication, I came to know we are using windows authentication.

So my question will be changed to something like this,

**What are the possible ways to get a SPlist data using SOAP/Webservices, using "_vti_bin/authentication.asmx" and then "_vti_bin/lists.asmx" "GetListItems()". Keeping in mind that I dont wanna use .Net(web reference) as I am developing it for a Windows Vista Gadget which will be built using HTML/Scripting language**

Cheers

**More Explanation:**

I tried given answer code spinets but I didn't got any success, **I also came to know that a client is using basic Authentication and then Kerbos authentication somewhere between servers**,  Now I tried this code, which isn't working either,

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Sharepoint List Browser</title>
</head>
<body style="width:400px; height:400px;">
<div id = "abc">
<button id = "btnFindLists" type="button">Click Me!</button>
<div id="mainContent">
   <p>1</p>  <!--  -- that p will be returned -->
  <p>2</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $('document').ready(function () {
    $('#btnFindLists').bind('click', findLists);
  });
  function findLists()
  {
    $.ajax(
    {
        type:'GET',
        url:'https://usa2020.domainabc.com/portal/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx',
        data:"username=domainabc\userabc&password=apassword",
        success: function(data){
        alert('successful');
      }
    });
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

"alert" function doesn't work in a Gadget.

I tried Falak's Code as this

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Sharepoint List Browser</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $('document').ready(function () {
    $('#btnFindLists').bind('click', findLists);
  });
  function findLists()
  {
    $.getJSON("https://usa2020.domainabc.com/portal/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx", {
      sucess: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
        $("#mainContent p").first().html(data);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
</head>
<body style="width:400px; height:400px;">
<div id = "abc">
<button id = "btnFindLists" type="button">Click Me!</button>
<div id="mainContent">
   <p>1</p>  <!--  -- that p will be returned -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Simply doesn't work like others, possible reason could be windows authentication.

Cheers

**EDIT 2:**
**Another thing I would like to add now, which is I can't get to Webservices until I logon to ISA server, thats another clue i got.**

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, considering you've already given the answer yourself. In other words, you say you want to use web services, even the specific web services you will use, and then you ask what you should use?

Comment: Hi Bjorn Problem is I dont know how to do this tho, I couldn't find any related code snippets tbh.

Comment: I couldn't find specific answer to my question but i gonna accept the closet one, but if you still come here and know the answer please do contact me as I dumbed this project for the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am thinking why wouldn't you use ListData.svc instead of Lists.asmx to get the list data. ListData.svc provides a way of getting information from a list (or lists using joins) using REST and you end up with is a nice RSS feed of list data, that you can consume with whatever client you would like.

Also, you don't have to create the Web reference as you mentioned in the question and still make your job done via client side scripting. Here is sample query to ListData.svc using jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $('document').ready(function () {
    $('#btnFindLists').bind('click', findLists);
  });
  function findLists()
  {
    alert('Hello World!');
    $.getJSON("/_vti_bin/ListData.svc", {
      sucess: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
        $("#mainContent p").first().html(data);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Falak, so if i use this code snippet, do i have to make any changes to server side and whether it will work with Sharepoiint 2007 or not.
Cheers

Comment: and how windows authentication will gonna work in this case

Comment: one more thing, In gadgets "alert" function doesn;t work

Comment: when you querying ListData.svc and if your SharePoint web application is configured using Windows Authentication with either NTLM or kerberos, your browser will either transmit your credentials automatically. To handle that,you can redirect the user to the regular SharePoint login page.
here is a link,you can refer to it.
http://www.silver-it.com/node/73

Comment: You can only use ListData.svc in SharePoint 2010 and for 2007 you have to use Lists.asmx. For using the above mentioned script you don't have to make any server side changes.

Comment: thanks bro, I just realized, I was wondering if i can chat with you about this topic for few minutes please ?

Comment: Sorry, I will have to run for a meeting shortly. Post your comments and I will try to get back to you asap.

Comment: sure, I try same code for Lists.asmx

Comment: I tried it with list.asmx, but no success, i think I need to pass credentials, so someone told me to use $.ajax and pass credentials as data, so gonna try that, if you know anything better please let me know :) thanks

Comment: Hi there ,
Have you tried SPServices>
Check it out.

Comment: Hi, someone told me to try it and i think i did, but does it work with sharepoint 2007, then Over SSL, and does windows authentication as well ? :) cheers

Comment: Yes it does.Try it and see it got lots of samples too

Comment: I tried finding tutorials but couldn't find one for what I want :S